# How to pull latitude longitude combinations from and external file

Tags: javascript, google-maps, variables, external

I am building a series of Google Maps in the project.

My code in general has this format:

```
var variableName = [
(lng:39.4455676,lat:47.55566),
(lng:39.4455676,lat:47.55566),
(lng:39.4455676,lat:47.55566),
(lng:39.4455676,lat:47.55566),
(lng:39.4455676,lat:47.55566),
.... and 13000 lines...
(lng:39.4455676,lat:47.55566),
],
```

Then, second time this variable is called here:

```
    variableName = new google.maps.Polygon({
            path: variableName,
            strokeColor: '#000000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillOpacity: 0.1
        });
```

What I would like to do is to PULL these 13000 lines of Lat and LONGitude from an external text, XML files via Javascript.

The reason?

My current code in HTML is 22000 lines (for just 7 administrative districs but I need 69), even though my Dreamweaver is installed ona very powerful quadcore ,it take solid 10 second before I can edit any code in there.

Any suggestion of help will be appreciated.

so basically:

I need to know how to use

that will have ONLY sets of Lat Lng values for 1 variable
then apply this rule to all variables and then pull these data into the main HTML file where the main scrip resides

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for Javascript.  `(39,4455676,47,55566)` will return `55566`.  Not sure if you want an array of objects or an array of arrays, but if you fix the syntax then you can simply put it in a different js file and include it prior to the js file with the rest of the code in it.

Comment: For starters, you should use brackets `[]` (array of arrays) or curly brackets `{}` (array of objects) around the latlongs. Also, you can't have the numeric commas in there, only the seperators. So `(39,4455676,47,55566)` should look something like this: `[394455676,4755566]`

Comment: Possibly related question: [Loading CSV with FileReader to make JS Objects for Map Markers (Maps API)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921096/loading-csv-with-filereader-to-make-js-objects-for-map-markers-maps-api)

Comment: Could you detail what the problem is after you define data in external javascript or JSON files? Your edit "ONLY sets of Lat Lng values for 1 variable then apply this rule to all variables" does not translate well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `fileReader` to get the contents of a file.

```
var freader = new FileReader(); // create the reader
freader.onload = function (evt) {  // set onload event
    var result = evt.target.result;  // get the result
    // to do. Extract the data
};
freader.readAsText(fileName);  // start loading
```

More on `fileReader` here [MDN filereader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

I will assume you know how to parse a string of data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want to have to open a ginormous file every time you need to edit the code, due to the size of your variable. Luckily, you don't need to do any 'pulling' or reading of files to accomplish this.

Simply, place your big `variableName` in a separate .js file by itself, and include it BEFORE the main script in your HTML. For instance, your HTML can look like this:

```
<script src="js/bigvariable.js">
<script src="js/main.js">
```

And `bigvariable.js` should look like this:

```
var variableName = [
(39,4455676,47,55566),
(39,4455676,47,55566),
(39,4455676,47,55566),
(39,4455676,47,55566),
(39,4455676,47,55566),
.... and 13000 lines...
(39,4455676,47,55566),
];
```

Your `main.js` will automatically have access to `variableName`.

Also, see my comment below your original post for recommendations on your format/syntax.

Comment: thank you, yes exactly I simply do not want to have a ginormous file to be edited each time.

these are two examples of my longitude and latitude  codes:

var jabrayilCoords = [
{lng:46.7717171,lat:39.445937},
{lng:46.7786264,lat:39.4386291},

and

new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),

Comment: I my file I have several variables

jabrail
shusha
agdam
zangilan
etc.
as you can see there is no pattern in the variable names (that way it is easier for the editor who will come after me to  relate to the administrative districts names)

can you please show if I am right?

so as far as I understand:

Comment: <script src="js/agdam.js">
<script src="js/jabrail.js">
<script src="js/shusha.js">

should only include what? the sets of lang lat values ???

Comment: I would include all the variables in a single file if possible, especially if each one of your variables is a different district. If you plan on having over 60 districts, that would mean having to link to over 60 scripts, which is not good at all. My recommendation is to place all your variables into a single `districts.js` file which a user can search with their text editor.

Comment: Your script can include all the variables and latlongs that you don't want to load in the main file. My recommendation is you have only two scripts: one to hold your main code, the other to hold all your variables with latlongs.

Answer (score 0):

[Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple) for `new google.maps.Polygon` gives an example of the `path` argument as

```
[
   {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
   {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
   {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
]
```

which is an array of coordinate objects with `lat` and `lng` properties using `.` as the decimal separator. Your first step will be to convert text files into this format, say

```
var variableName = [
    {lat: 39.4455676, lng: 47.55566},
     .... and 13000 lines...
],
```

for a javascript file which can be included as per usual. The other option would be to convert the coordinate arrays to a JSON string file with quotes around the property names.looking more like

```
[
   {"lat":39.4455676,"lng":47.55566},
   ... and so on
]
```

A quick search of SO for "how to include a JSON file" turned up 491 results so I won't attempt to repeat an answer here.